# Update SQL CE Table Data

Tags: database-design, sql-server-ce, synchronization

I need to create an application where i can update the data once in a while. I'm trying to figure out the best way so I can create the schema...should i create a database with the tables i need and just copy from the modified database i have? but then i lose relationships that should make my life easier inside the application. Or create scripts with a tool (Red Gate Data Comparer) and run the script in the client to update the data in the tables.

Any suggestions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Sync Framework works OK once you get used to it. It does have some limitations and quirks though.

Comment: I will check the features deeper. You think this could work with numerous clients and 1 server?

Comment: @gtas: That is what we are doing currently. Newer versions of the Sync Framework supports peer-2-peer syncing features, although I have not used that.